# Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#439>", line 3, in <module> print(l.text) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently scraping Linkedin Job directory using selenium in python shell

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?locationId=sg%3A0&f_TP=1%2C2&orig=FCTD&trk=jobs_jserp_posted_one_week')

a = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('job-title-text')
b = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('company-name-text')
c = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('job-location')
d = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('job-description')

#There are 50 pages of jobs therefore I specified a range of 55

for e in range(55):
    for g in a:
        print(g.text)
    for h in b:
        print(h.text)
    for i in c:
        print(i.text)
    for j in d:
        print(j.text)

k = driver.find_element_by_class_name('next-btn')
k.click()
Job = []
Job.append(a)
Job.append(b)
Job.append(c)
Job.append(d)

for e in range(55):
    for l in Job:
        print(l.text)

k = driver.find_element_by_class_name('next-btn')
k.click()
```

This code is not working and I have been struggling and tried various methods of solving this issue. It will be great if I can get the correct solution.

Comment: what did you mean by not working?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File “<pyshell#439>”, line 3, in <module> print(l.text) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'                         I am getting the above error

Comment: You're appending `list` to `Job`. Try this `for lst in Job: for item in lst: print(item.text)`

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you will get multidemensional array in `Job`.
Try to replace

```
 Job.append(a) 
 Job.append(b)
 Job.append(c)
 Job.append(d)
```

with

```
Job += a
Job += b
Job += c
Job += d
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because variable "a" is a list.
You can debug to see what's in Job list.
I think the Job list like this Job=[[a], [b], [c], [d]] in your code.